# How to downgrade to GCC v.7 (Ubuntu 22.04 LTS)?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gcc, compiler-errors

I was using g++ v11 and got a compiler error (" *internal compiler error: in expand... ") which as far as i read was introduced in version 8 of g++.

So i tried to downgrade to g++ v7 just to end with my assignment (university stuff) but since I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 i couldn't in any possible way because it won't let me download any obsolete package (deleting g++ doesn't sound like a solution).

The message after trying to install g++7 is "Package g++-7 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source".

Do you know how can I downgrade to g++-7?

Thank you all for your help and if you know other solutions it would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you can share what is that internal compiler error and the respective code?

Comment: Note that one way of dealing with internal compiler error is to simplify the code a bit where it's throwing this error. Works sometimes..

Comment: Did you try downloading the gcc-7 package for 18.04 and installing it? Note that askubuntu.com is more specialized for this kind of question.

Comment: @kiner_shah the error is (it wasn't letting me post this before, idk why) internal compiler error: in expand_expr_real_1, at expr.c:10281, the expression a call to Default constructor of My HashMap implementation ( i guess the problem is related to dynamic allocation of an array.
I cannot simplify code because it's a library i've been building for months and our professor told us that we could get this problem (in fact i'm also going to ask him how to solve this)

Comment: You can click on Edit option and include all relevant information there - your error log, code, etc.

Comment: Do you necessarily require gcc? Otherwise you could try using clang, also easily available from the package repositories

Comment: @codeling Yes, i Mean my professor tests our libreries using gcc and he strongly reccomend to use that one because he takes no responsabilities in case of compiling error or something (it means i will get 0/30 which isn't the best)